# Smack XMPP connection not connecting over 4G network

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I am using the latest Smack library 4.3.1. The XMPP connection is working fine
with WiFi but it's not working with 4G network.

Here is my code for creating a connection with XMPP.

```
 configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
        configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword(this.userName, this.password);
        configBuilder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
        configBuilder.setServiceName(Constants.HOST);
        configBuilder.setPort(Constants.PORT);
        configBuilder.setHost(Constants.HOST);
        configBuilder.setDebuggerEnabled(Isdebugmode);
        configBuilder.setResource(PDCustomer.getResource());
        configBuilder.setSendPresence(true);
        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());
        connection.setPacketReplyTimeout(30000);
        connection.addConnectionListener(XmppConnection.this);
        connection.addAsyncStanzaListener(XmppConnection.this, null);
   try {
            connection.connect();
           connection.login(userName, password);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            printlog("CONNECT IO EXCEPTION:" + e.getMessage());

        } catch (SmackException e) {
            printlog("CONNECT SMACK EXCEPTION:" + e.getMessage());

        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            printlog("CONNECT XMPP EXCEPTION:" + e.getMessage());

        }
```

Comment: Where you got exact problem? I think you may get an connection error while changing from Wifi to Mobile data or from Mobile data to Wifi.

Comment: did you run a packet capture to see where the request is getting rejected?

Comment: i did check connection other app are working fine but my app still have this issue  @harsh patel

Comment: But when you got an issue? While switching internet connectivity like Wifi to Mobile data?

Comment: i did not switch network my mobile 4g data is on all the time @Harsh Patel

Comment: Check my post and try to connect @Bharatsingh

Comment: This issue doesn't exist but if you seems something problem in connection then please take a reference over their https://github.com/saveendhiman/XMPPSample_Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested below code in 4G network

Create new class of **XMPPConnection**

```
public class XMPPConnection implements ConnectionListener, ChatManagerListener, RosterListener, ChatMessageListener, PingFailedListener {
private static final String TAG = "XMPPConnection";

public static final String HOST = "XX.XX.XXX.XX"; //Replace this value
public static final int PORT = 5222;
public static final String SERVICE = "XX.XX.XXX.XX"; //Replace this value
public static String USERNAME = ""; // Replace this value
public static String PASSWORD = ""; //Replace this value
public static String TEST_JID = "android_dummy"; // Only for testing purpose

private static XMPPConnection mInstance = new XMPPConnection();

private AbstractXMPPConnection mConnection;

private ChatManager mChatmanager;
private Chat mChat;

private Context mContext;

private String mUserName = "";
private String mPassword = "";

public XMPPConnection() {
}

public static XMPPConnection getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

//Initialize
public void init(String userId, String pwd, Context context) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException {
    Log.i("XMPP", "Initializing!");

    this.mUserName = userId;
    this.mPassword = pwd;
    this.mContext = context;

    if (userId.contains("@")) {
        this.mUserName = userId.split("@")[0];
        Log.i("UserId", this.mUserName);
    }
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword(mUserName, mPassword);
    configBuilder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
    configBuilder.setServiceName(SERVICE);
    configBuilder.setHost(HOST);
    configBuilder.setPort(PORT);
    configBuilder.setResource("");
    //configBuilder.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    mConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());

    PingManager pingManager = PingManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection);
    pingManager.setPingInterval(300); // 2.5 min
    pingManager.registerPingFailedListener(this);

    mChatmanager.getInstanceFor(mConnection).addChatListener(this);
    ReconnectionManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection).enableAutomaticReconnection();

    mConnection.addConnectionListener(this);

    connectConnection(context);
}

public void connectConnection(final Context context) {
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> connectionThread = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            // Create a connection
            try {
                mConnection.connect();

                if (mConnection != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground: ServerStatus:Connected= " + mConnection.isConnected());
                    login(context);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground : ServerStatus : IOException = " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (SmackException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground : ServerStatus : SmackException = " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground : ServerStatus : XMPPException = " + e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }
    };
    connectionThread.execute();
}

public void login(Context context) {
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "login: USERNAME:" + mUserName + " PASSWORD:" + mPassword);

        mConnection.login(mUserName, mPassword);
        if (mConnection.isAuthenticated()) {
            Log.i("LOGIN", "Yey! We're connected to the Xmpp server!");
            sendMessage("", TEST_JID, "", "", "", "android_dummy", "android", "android", context);
        }


    } catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Login : Exception = " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void sendMessage(String message, String to, String from, String dattingId, String deviceToken, String senderName, String senderOSName, String opponentOSName, Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;

    if (mConnection.isConnected() == true) {
        Log.i(TAG, "sendMsg: Sending Message...");
        // Assume we've created an XMPPConnection name "connection".
        mChatmanager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection);
        mChat = mChatmanager.createChat("" + to, this);

        // Original code
        try {
            Message msg = new Message();
            // Set message
            msg.setBody(message);
            msg.setType(Message.Type.chat);
            msg.setTo("" + to);
            msg.setFrom("" + from);

            Log.i(TAG, "Message to send : " + msg.toXML());

            mChat.sendMessage(msg);
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "sendMsg : Unable to send Message.");
    }
}

// Disconnect Function
public void disconnectConnection() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mConnection != null && mConnection.isConnected())
                mConnection.disconnect();
            mConnection = null;
        }
    }).start();
}

@Override
public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
    if (mConnection.isConnected() && mConnection != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Message " + message);
    }
}

@Override
public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean createdLocally) {
    Log.i(TAG, "chatCreated()");
    chat.addMessageListener(this);
}

@Override
public void connected(org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection connection) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Listener connected = " + connection.getUser());
}

@Override
public void authenticated(org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection connection, boolean resumed) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Listener authenticated = " + connection.getUser());
    Log.i(TAG, "Listener authenticated = resumed : " + resumed);
}

@Override
public void connectionClosed() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Listener connectionClosed");
}

@Override
public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Listener connectionClosedOnError = " + e.getMessage());
}

@Override
public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Listener reconnectionSuccessful");
    if (mContext != null) {
        sendMessage("", TEST_JID, "", "", "", "android_dummy", "android", "android", mContext);
    }
}

@Override
public void reconnectingIn(int seconds) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Listener reconnectingIn = " + seconds);
}

@Override
public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Listener reconnectionFailed = " + e.getMessage());
}

@Override
public void pingFailed() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Listener pingFailed");
}

@Override
public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> addresses) {

}

@Override
public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> addresses) {

}

@Override
public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> addresses) {

}

@Override
public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
    Log.i(TAG, "presenceChanged: " + presence.getClass().toString());
}
```

}

Now call **init()** method like,

```
// Check XMPP connection
    try {
        XMPPConnection.getInstance().init(USER_JABBERID, USER_JABBER_PASSWORD, HomeActivity.this);
    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```